# How does the eloquent pivot consult are written?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm developing an ecommere. The thing is that I´ve made a function `belongsToMany` in `user` model for the cart to save many products, called it `carrito`. But in the controller, when I wanna get the `id` of the products, gives me an error as if the attributes didn't exist. What I want to do is take data from an existing table `carts`(with the function `carrito`) and insert that in a new one called `pedidos`

heres the code...

Model : **Users**

```php
public function carrito(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'cart')
                ->withPivot('product_id', 'user_id', 'quantity');

}
```

**Controller**

```php
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $user =Auth::user();
    $producto = $user->carrito;    

    Pedido::create([
        'user_id'=>Auth::User()->id,
        'puntosretiros_id' => $request->get('puntoE'),
        'product_id' => $producto->product_id,
        'quantity' => $producto->quantity,
        'total'=> $request->input('total'),
    ]);    
    $pedido->save();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: table name mentioned in the relation(`cart`) is different form the one you stated(`carts`)

Comment: `$producto = $user->carrito;` will return a collection of records. So you won't be able to access values like this, `$producto->product_id`.

Comment: If you need to insert all records from the relation to new one, then loop through `$producto->product_id` and make an array of data, then insert that that data to table

Answer (score 0):

If you want some advice, I would suggest a some slight changes to make your code clearer:

---

**1) Models**

**User**

A `User` has a `Cart`

```
/**
 * A User has a cart.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
 */
public function cart()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Cart::class);
}
```

**Cart**

A `Cart` belongs to a `User`

A `Cart` has many `Product`s

```
/**
 * A Cart belongs to a User.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function cart()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

/**
 * A Cart has many Products.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot(['quantity']);
}
```

A `Product` can be in many `Cart`s

```
/**
 * A Product can be in many Carts.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Cart::class)->withPivot(['quantity']);
}
```

---

**2) Relationships**

With your models configured this way you can now access your data like so;

```
// Load a user with all their carts and products
$user = User::with(['carts.products])->find(1);

// Get a specfic cart
$cart = $user->carts->first();

// Get the products in their cart
$products = $cart->products;

// Get quantity of the first product in the cart
$quantity = $products->first()->pivot->quantity;
```

---

Now all of this is just a basic example but demos what you can do with a few relationships and `Pivot` models & attributes.